# Why am I getting the error "Error:(6, 39) error: cannot find symbol class gd"?

Tags: java, android

I hired a freelancer to write for me a code for android application, when he is done with code he sent it to me. I tried to import it with Eclipse and Android Studio, added appcompat_v7 library and google play services which is used by the program.
I can't get an apk since there is one error i couldn't resolve

Error: "cannot find symbol class gd"

Code where error refers to:

```
 import com.google.android.gms.internal.gd;
```

I have experience in C# more than in java or android applications, i am trying to learn more about it.
Btw: i tried to contact the freelancer but he in not giving me anything.
so would you please help me to fix this!?